# Android Browsers Absolute Position Issue

Tags: android, browser, css-position

I have tried my best to solve the issue in Android Browsers Regarding Absolute Positioning.

When i Try to Put to image with absolute positioning then it places it on top of the page.

It only happened when i do it live (Means when i try to put it through some event) .

If any one has some answers or guidance would be highly appreciated.